# How to calculate $P(A, B | C)$ from Bayesian Network?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

I have this bayesian network: 
`A -> B -> C` I need to calculate $P(A, B|C)$. How can I do that? 

I tried doing:

$P(A,B | C) = P(A|B,C)P(B|C)$

But I don't understand where to go from that considering I don't have any CPT that can help me in solving $P(A|B,C)$. I only have CPT's where $B$ is dependent on $A$ and $C$ is dependent on $B$. 
Also, what should I read to be able to solve such weird flows' probabilities in the BN?

Comment: Try the definition of conditional probability, $P(X|Y) = \frac{P(X, Y)}{P(Y)}$

Comment: So long as you know the marginal probabilities $P(A)$ and $P(C)$ you can calculate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your network, the CPDs are P(A), P(B|A) and P(C|B). Also, C is independent of A given B.

$$
\begin{align}
P(AB|C)&=P(C|AB)P(AB)/P(C) \\
&=P(C|B)P(B|A)P(A)/(\sum_B P(C|B) \sum_A P(A)P(B|A))
\end{align}
$$

P(C) is calculated by summing out A and B from the joined distribution.

It's not a "weird" form, instead rather basic. You can read about **conditional independence** and **information pass** in the field of graphical models to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

note1: you also have the probability table for $A$. You can think of it as the CPT for $P(A|\phi)$.

note2: at least when beginning with bayesian networks, I think it helps a lot to use the full notation $P(B=b|A=a)$, to understand what you're doing. Think of $A$ as a binary random variable that can take $a \in [0,1]$

If the network was only `A->B`, to derive $P(B=b|A=a)$, you would do:

$P(A=a, B=b) = P(A=a)P(B=b|A=a)$
$P(B=b) = \sum_{a\in A}P(A=a)P(B=b|A=a)$

so:

$P(A=a|B=b) = \frac{P(A=a,B=b)}{P(B=b)}$

for 3 variables, just apply these Bayesian equations more.